# Php Wordpress- can't get the the_title of a clicked element

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I was trying get the the_title() of clicked element from custom post type.

```
<a  href='index.php?hello=$menuName'> <?php $menuName = the_title(); ?> </a>
<?php echo $_GET[hello]; ?>
```

But it is not returning the title name, it's just giving me the variable name.

I just want to use the value here to set the menu name

```
$menuName = $_GET['hello'];
$menu_header = get_term_by('name', $menuName , 'nav_menu');
```

Here is the full code.

```
<div class="dropdown-content">

<?php  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'location', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<a  href='index.php?hello=$menuName'> <?php $menuName = the_title(); ?> </a>
<?php echo $_GET[hello]; ?>
<?php   
endwhile;

function runMyFunction() {
$menuName = $_GET['hello'];
$menu_header = get_term_by('name', $menuName , 'nav_menu');
$menu_header_id = $menu_header->term_id;
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
//set the menu to the new location and save into database
$locations['primary'] = $menu_header_id;
set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations);
   }
if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
runMyFunction();
 ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the following code :

```
<a  href='index.php?hello=$menuName'> <?php $menuName = the_title(); ?> </a>
```

You try to set a variable that is still undefined in your `href`. Furthermore, in the loop, `the_title()` returns the current post title, so it's weird to do this way...

last point is the single quotes in php doesn't interpret variables, contrary to double quotes. and if you want to make it a propre way, i'd recommand you set your link this way :

```
<a href="index.php?hello=<?php echo $menuName; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying your suggestion, let's see

Comment: but how can i get the title, should i write like this 
<a href="index.php?hello=<?php echo $menuName=the_title(); ?>"></a>

Comment: `<a href="index.php?hello=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"></a>`

Comment: Thank you man,,,thank you so much,,,i'm sooo much grateful to you,,,,i can't make you understand how much you helped me,, i'm actually a beginner....Thank you,,,

Comment: Happy to help ;p

Comment: can you just help me with another thing, if i want to get the content and title of the same clicked element, how can i do that?

Comment: if you search this on google with the exact same words, you'll find this in less than a minute